# Faster SQL statement - currently have a slow Subquery would JOIN be faster?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join

I have a SQL statement with a sub query in it. Since adding the subquery it now takes about 10 times longer to preform the statement.
i've been reading that JOIN could possibly be faster but im not exactly proficient in SQL to know how to implement a JOIN statement, or that a JOIN could even be used for my problem.

My current SQL statement, with the subquery inside a IIF statement.

```
SELECT Brand, 
       DESCRIPTION AS Model, 
       SECONDDESCRIPTION AS Description, 
       PRODUCT AS [Product Code], 
       TYPE AS [Batch Type], 
       INACTIVE, CORE AS [Core Range], 
       BATCH,
       IIF(t.BATCH = 
              (SELECT TOP 1 t2.BATCH 
               FROM INVXLS AS t2 
               WHERE t2.TYPE = '' 
               AND t2.PRODUCT = t.PRODUCT),     
           t.ON_HAND - t.CUSTORD, t.ON_HAND) AS SOH 
FROM INVXLS as t
```

explaining what the subquery is doing is a little wordy so if that requires more explanation then please comment.

Im working in VB.NET, and accessing a MS ACCESS Database.

Is there a way to switch this out for a JOIN statement and if so, what would that JOIN statement look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SELECT TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is dangerous.  But that is not your question.

For performance, you want an index on `INVXLS(PRODUCT, TYPE, BATCH)`:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_INVXLS_PRODUCT_TYPE_BATCH ON INVXLS(PRODUCT, TYPE, BATCH);
```

Comment: Will the the Create Index in anyway edit the existing Database, or it will soley be adding an index to the data as it "selects" in imports into my datatable?

Comment: @AndyAndromeda . . . `create index` is a database operation to speed the processing of the query, which is in the database.

Comment: THANKYOU GORDON! iv just learnt something new, and yes adding the index has actually now made the select statement work faster then before it had the subquery. So at the moment i still have the subquery just as it was, only modification was the index.

not to get too sidetracked, i do have another question regarding my IFF statement

Comment: my current IFF statement gets the TOP 1 Batch, 
how would i get the TOP 1 batch that has the largest ON_HAND number. 

iv tried 
`IIF(t.BATCH = 
              (SELECT TOP 1 t2.BATCH
               FROM INVXLS AS t2
               WHERE t2.TYPE = '' 
               AND t2.PRODUCT = t.PRODUCT
ORDER BY ON_HAND desc)    
 t.ON_HAND - t.CUSTORD, t.ON_HAND) AS SOH

while this query will run i don't get the desired results. with the maths thats outside the select statement / inside the iff statement. `t.ON_HAND - t.CUSTORD, t.ON_HAND) AS SOH`

Comment: I would also suggest converting to an `EXISTS`. In some circumstances this might improve performance (depending on whether the query planner is already smart enough to have optimised this)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to convert it to `JOIN` (`LEFT JOIN`) and it will be faster than subquery as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.Brand, 
       T.DESCRIPTION AS Model, 
       T.SECONDDESCRIPTION AS Description, 
       T.PRODUCT AS [Product Code], 
       T.TYPE AS [Batch Type], 
       T.INACTIVE, T.CORE AS [Core Range], 
       T.BATCH,
       Case when tt.batch is not null then t.ON_HAND - t.CUSTORD else t.ON_HAND end AS SOH 
FROM INVXLS as t LEFT JOIN INVXLS as tt
  ON tt.product = t.product AND tt.TYPE = '' AND t.batch = tt.batch
```

Comment: I get an error message when i try to run this statement. 
`IERRORinfo.getdescription failed with E_Fail`

Comment: Can you please try to resolve the column name or minor syntax issue? I have given you the approach. Or share proper error message.

Comment: I did try all sorts of variations to fix it. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get it to work. Gordon's idea of adding an index actually worked with no need to change the existing query.

Comment: A left join can cause double counting if joins are not what you expect. Also the `distinct` introduces it's own performance issues.

Comment: There is no counting in the query and the performance of `DISTINCT` is better than the subquery in the question. But thanks for the comment with details.